# How to access the elements in a sencha touch 2 store

Tags: sencha-touch-2, store

I am new to Sencha Touch so I am still struggling with the usage of stores.

I have created this store which I am successfully using to populate a list:

```
Ext.define('EventApp.store.events',{ 
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

        config: {
            model: 'EventApp.model.event',
            autoLoad: true,
            storeId: 'events',
            proxy:{
                type:'ajax',
                url: './resources/EventData.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'events'
                }
            }

            }

});
```

As I mentiones this store works correctly when referenced from a list and I can display the contents of it. Therefore I am assuming the store is correctly defined.

Unfortunately when I try to access the store from a controller for one of my views (which will be used to populate the items of a carousel) I don't seem to get any data back from the store. The code I am using is the following:

```
onEventCarouselInitialize : function(compon, eOptions) {
    var past = compon.getPast();
    var eventsStore = Ext.getStore('events');
    eventsStore.each(function(record){
        console.log('Record =',record); //<-- this never gets executed.
    },this);
}
```

I have tried executing an eventsStore.load() on an eventsStore.sync() but I never seem to get any elements available in the store.

What am I missing?

Thanks
Oriol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i have understand is, perhaps your store data has not been loaded when you are accessing it. So put you each() function on store inside this for delaying 500ms:

```
Ext.Function.defer(function(){
    // Put each() here
}, 500);
```

Have a try by delaying more or less.